# Software to convert .NEF to .JPG

Tags: windows, gratis, linux, photography, media-converter

I love using [View NX2](http://www.nikonusa.com/en/Nikon-Products/Product/Imaging-Software/ViewNX-2.html) to import, organize and edit my pictures from my Nikon D3200 camera. What I do not love is converting images with it. It can be quite slow when converting and can take overnight to convert 30 pictures. I do not have the best computer in the world, so sometimes I like to outsource tasks to my VPS and let it handle all the tough jobs my computer can't handle. Since I know converting images can be a tough job, I would like my VPS to handle this while still be able to convert a quick image from my Windows computer.

I am looking for software that can convert .NEF (RAW) pictures to .JPG with no or very little loss in quality that has support for both Linux (command line) and Windows.

Requirements:

- Must have support for both Linux (CentOS) and Windows (7)
- Must be able to "batch convert" the images (IE I don't want to convert one file at a time. On Linux, this should recursively select all the files in a folder and convert them to a specified output folder)
- Must convert with little or no loss in quality
- Must output to .JPG or .JPEG
- Must be gratis (free)
- Shouldn't use *too* much processing and RAM power but I know this can be hard to find when dealing with images so its not a set requirement, but it would be nice to have

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can read NEF files to output jpeg or a wide range of other formats.

- Free/Gratis
- Cross platform
- Command Line conversion
- Batch conversion
- Lots of input & output formats:

> ```
> ~$ identify -list
> format     Format  Module    Mode  Description
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   3FR  DNG       r--   Hasselblad CFV/H3D39II
>     A* RAW       rw+   Raw alpha samples
>   AAI* AAI       rw+   AAI Dune image
>    AI  PDF       rw-   Adobe Illustrator CS2
>   ART* ART       rw-   PFS: 1st Publisher Clip Art
>   ARW  DNG       r--   Sony Alpha Raw Image Format
>   AVI  MPEG      r--   Microsoft Audio/Visual Interleaved
>   AVS* AVS       rw+   AVS X image
>     B* RAW       rw+   Raw blue samples
>   BGR* BGR       rw+   Raw blue, green, and red samples
>  BGRA* BGR       rw+   Raw blue, green, red, and alpha samples
>   BIE* JBIG      rw-   Joint Bi-level Image experts Group interchange format (2.0)
>   BMP* BMP       rw-   Microsoft Windows bitmap image
>  BMP2* BMP       -w-   Microsoft Windows bitmap image (V2)
>  BMP3* BMP       -w-   Microsoft Windows bitmap image (V3)
>   BRF* BRAILLE   -w-   BRF ASCII Braille format
>     C* RAW       rw+   Raw cyan samples
>   CAL* CALS      rw-   Continuous Acquisition and Life-cycle Support Type 1
>        Specified in MIL-R-28002 and MIL-PRF-28002
>  CALS* CALS      rw-   Continuous Acquisition and Life-cycle Support Type 1
>        Specified in MIL-R-28002 and MIL-PRF-28002
> CANVAS* XC        r--   Constant image uniform color
> CAPTION* CAPTION   r--   Caption
>   CIN* CIN       rw-   Cineon Image File
>   CIP* CIP       -w-   Cisco IP phone image format
>  CLIP* CLIP      -w+   Image Clip Mask
>  CMYK* CMYK      rw+   Raw cyan, magenta, yellow, and black samples
> CMYKA* CMYK      rw+   Raw cyan, magenta, yellow, black, and alpha samples
>   CR2  DNG       r--   Canon Digital Camera Raw Image Format
>   CRW  DNG       r--   Canon Digital Camera Raw Image Format
>   CUR* CUR       rw-   Microsoft icon
>   CUT* CUT       r--   DR Halo
>   DCM* DCM       r--   Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine image
>        DICOM is used by the medical community for images like X-rays.  The
>        specification, "Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine
>        (DICOM)", is available at http://medical.nema.org/.  In particular,
>        see part 5 which describes the image encoding (RLE, JPEG, JPEG-LS),
>        and supplement 61 which adds JPEG-2000 encoding.
>   DCR  DNG       r--   Kodak Digital Camera Raw Image File
>   DCX* PCX       rw+   ZSoft IBM PC multi-page Paintbrush
>   DDS* DDS       r--   Microsoft DirectDraw Surface
> DFONT* TTF       r--   Multi-face font package (Freetype 2.5.2)
>  DJVU* DJVU      r--   D�j� vu
>        See http://www.djvuzone.org/ for details about the DJVU format.  The
>        DJVU 1.2 specification is available there and at
>        ftp://swrinde.nde.swri.edu/pub/djvu/documents/.
>   DNG  DNG       r--   Digital Negative
>   DOT  DOT       ---   Graphviz
>   DPX* DPX       rw-   SMPTE 268M-2003 (DPX 2.0)
>        Digital Moving Picture Exchange Bitmap, Version 2.0.
>        See SMPTE 268M-2003 specification at http://www.smtpe.org
>        
>  EPDF  PDF       rw-   Encapsulated Portable Document Format
>   EPI  PS        rw-   Encapsulated PostScript Interchange format
>   EPS  PS        rw-   Encapsulated PostScript
>  EPS2* PS2       -w-   Level II Encapsulated PostScript
>  EPS3* PS3       -w+   Level III Encapsulated PostScript
>  EPSF  PS        rw-   Encapsulated PostScript
>  EPSI  PS        rw-   Encapsulated PostScript Interchange format
>   EPT  EPT       rw-   Encapsulated PostScript with TIFF preview
>  EPT2  EPT       rw-   Encapsulated PostScript Level II with TIFF preview
>  EPT3  EPT       rw+   Encapsulated PostScript Level III with TIFF preview
>   ERF  DNG       r--   Epson RAW Format
>   EXR  EXR       rw-   High Dynamic-range (HDR)
>   FAX* FAX       rw+   Group 3 FAX
>        FAX machines use non-square pixels which are 1.5 times wider than
>        they are tall but computer displays use square pixels, therefore
>        FAX images may appear to be narrow unless they are explicitly
>        resized using a geometry of "150x100%".
>        
>  FITS* FITS      rw-   Flexible Image Transport System
> FRACTAL* PLASMA    r--   Plasma fractal image
>   FTS* FTS       rw-   Flexible Image Transport System
>     G* RAW       rw+   Raw green samples
>    G3* FAX       rw-   Group 3 FAX
>   GIF* GIF       rw+   CompuServe graphics interchange format
> GIF87* GIF       rw-   CompuServe graphics interchange format (version 87a)
> GRADIENT* GRADIENT  r--   Gradual linear passing from one shade to another
>  GRAY* GRAY      rw+   Raw gray samples
> GROUP4* TIFF      rw-   Raw CCITT Group4
>  HALD*           r--   Identity Hald color lookup table image
>   HDR* HDR       rw+   Radiance RGBE image format
> HISTOGRAM* HISTOGRAM -w-   Histogram of the image
>   HRZ* HRZ       rw-   Slow Scan TeleVision
>   HTM* HTML      -w-   Hypertext Markup Language and a client-side image map
>  HTML* HTML      -w-   Hypertext Markup Language and a client-side image map
>   ICB* TGA       rw-   Truevision Targa image
>   ICO* ICON      rw+   Microsoft icon
>  ICON* ICON      rw-   Microsoft icon
>  INFO  INFO      -w+   The image format and characteristics
> INLINE* INLINE    r--   Base64-encoded inline images
>   IPL* IPL       rw+   IPL Image Sequence
> ISOBRL* BRAILLE   -w-   ISO/TR 11548-1 format
>   J2C* JP2       rw-   JPEG-2000 Code Stream Syntax
>   J2K* JP2       rw-   JPEG-2000 Code Stream Syntax
>   JBG* JBIG      rw+   Joint Bi-level Image experts Group interchange format (2.0)
>  JBIG* JBIG      rw+   Joint Bi-level Image experts Group interchange format (2.0)
>   JNG* PNG       rw-   JPEG Network Graphics
>        See http://www.libpng.org/pub/mng/ for details about the JNG
>        format.
>   JP2* JP2       rw-   JPEG-2000 File Format Syntax
>   JPC* JP2       rw-   JPEG-2000 Code Stream Syntax
>  JPEG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (80)
>   JPG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (80)
>   JPX* JP2       rw-   JPEG-2000 File Format Syntax
>     K* RAW       rw+   Raw black samples
>   K25  DNG       r--   Kodak Digital Camera Raw Image Format
>   KDC  DNG       r--   Kodak Digital Camera Raw Image Format
> LABEL* LABEL     r--   Image label
>     M* RAW       rw+   Raw magenta samples
>   M2V  MPEG      rw+   MPEG Video Stream
>   M4V  MPEG      rw+   Raw MPEG-4 Video
>   MAC* MAC       r--   MAC Paint
>   MAP* MAP       rw-   Colormap intensities and indices
>   MAT  MAT       rw+   MATLAB level 5 image format
> MATTE* MATTE     -w+   MATTE format
>   MEF  DNG       r--   Mamiya Raw Image File
>  MIFF* MIFF      rw+   Magick Image File Format
>   MNG* PNG       rw+   Multiple-image Network Graphics (libpng 1.2.50)
>        See http://www.libpng.org/pub/mng/ for details about the MNG
>        format.
>  MONO* MONO      rw-   Raw bi-level bitmap
>   MOV  MPEG      rw+   MPEG Video Stream
>   MP4  MPEG      rw+   MPEG-4 Video Stream
>   MPC* MPC       rw+   Magick Persistent Cache image format
>  MPEG  MPEG      rw+   MPEG Video Stream
>   MPG  MPEG      rw+   MPEG Video Stream
>   MRW  DNG       r--   Sony (Minolta) Raw Image File
>   MSL* MSL       rw+   Magick Scripting Language
>  MSVG  SVG       rw+   ImageMagick's own SVG internal renderer
>   MTV* MTV       rw+   MTV Raytracing image format
>   MVG* MVG       rw-   Magick Vector Graphics
>   NEF  DNG       r--   Nikon Digital SLR Camera Raw Image File
>   NRW  DNG       r--   Nikon Digital SLR Camera Raw Image File
>  NULL* NULL      rw-   Constant image of uniform color
>     O* RAW       rw+   Raw opacity samples
>   ORF  DNG       r--   Olympus Digital Camera Raw Image File
>   OTB* OTB       rw-   On-the-air bitmap
>   OTF* TTF       r--   Open Type font (Freetype 2.5.2)
>   PAL* UYVY      rw-   16bit/pixel interleaved YUV
>  PALM* PALM      rw+   Palm pixmap
>   PAM* PNM       rw+   Common 2-dimensional bitmap format
> PANGO* PANGO     r--   Pango Markup Language (Pangocairo 1.36.1)   
> PATTERN* PATTERN   r--   Predefined pattern
>   PBM* PNM       rw+   Portable bitmap format (black and white)
>   PCD* PCD       rw-   Photo CD
>  PCDS* PCD       rw-   Photo CD
>   PCL  PCL       rw+   Printer Control Language
>   PCT* PICT      rw-   Apple Macintosh QuickDraw/PICT
>   PCX* PCX       rw-   ZSoft IBM PC Paintbrush
>   PDB* PDB       rw+   Palm Database ImageViewer Format
>   PDF  PDF       rw+   Portable Document Format
>  PDFA  PDF       rw+   Portable Document Archive Format
>   PEF  DNG       r--   Pentax Electronic File
>   PES* PES       r--   Embrid Embroidery Format
>   PFA* TTF       r--   Postscript Type 1 font (ASCII) (Freetype 2.5.2)
>   PFB* TTF       r--   Postscript Type 1 font (binary) (Freetype 2.5.2)
>   PFM* PFM       rw+   Portable float format
>   PGM* PNM       rw+   Portable graymap format (gray scale)
>   PGX* JP2       r--   JPEG-2000 VM Format
> PICON* XPM       rw-   Personal Icon
>  PICT* PICT      rw-   Apple Macintosh QuickDraw/PICT
>   PIX* PIX       r--   Alias/Wavefront RLE image format
> PJPEG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (80)
> PLASMA* PLASMA    r--   Plasma fractal image
>   PNG* PNG       rw-   Portable Network Graphics (libpng 1.2.50)
>        See http://www.libpng.org/ for details about the PNG format.
> PNG24* PNG       rw-   opaque 24-bit RGB (zlib 1.2.8)
> PNG32* PNG       rw-   opaque or transparent 32-bit RGBA
>  PNG8* PNG       rw-   8-bit indexed with optional binary transparency
>   PNM* PNM       rw+   Portable anymap
>   PPM* PNM       rw+   Portable pixmap format (color)
>  PREVIEW* PREVIEW   -w-   Show a preview an image enhancement, effect, or f/x
>    PS  PS        rw+   PostScript
>   PS2* PS2       -w+   Level II PostScript
>   PS3* PS3       -w+   Level III PostScript
>   PSB* PSD       rw+   Adobe Large Document Format
>   PSD* PSD       rw+   Adobe Photoshop bitmap
>  PTIF* TIFF      rw+   Pyramid encoded TIFF
>   PWP* PWP       r--   Seattle Film Works
>     R* RAW       rw+   Raw red samples
> RADIAL-GRADIENT* GRADIENT  r--   Gradual radial passing from one shade to another
>   RAF  DNG       r--   Fuji CCD-RAW Graphic File
>   RAS* SUN       rw+   SUN Rasterfile
>   RGB* RGB       rw+   Raw red, green, and blue samples
>  RGBA* RGB       rw+   Raw red, green, blue, and alpha samples
>  RGBO* RGB       rw+   Raw red, green, blue, and opacity samples
>   RLA* RLA       r--   Alias/Wavefront image
>   RLE* RLE       r--   Utah Run length encoded image
>   SCR* SCR       r--   ZX-Spectrum SCREEN$
>   SCT* SCT       r--   Scitex HandShake
>   SFW* SFW       r--   Seattle Film Works
>   SGI* SGI       rw+   Irix RGB image
> SHTML* HTML      -w-   Hypertext Markup Language and a client-side image map
>   SR2  DNG       r--   Sony Raw Format 2
>   SRF  DNG       r--   Sony Raw Format
> STEGANO* STEGANO   r--   Steganographic image
>   SUN* SUN       rw+   SUN Rasterfile
>   SVG  SVG       rw+   Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.40.1)
>  SVGZ  SVG       rw+   Compressed Scalable Vector Graphics (RSVG 2.40.1)
>  TEXT* TXT       rw+   Text
>   TGA* TGA       rw-   Truevision Targa image
> THUMBNAIL* THUMBNAIL -w+   EXIF Profile Thumbnail
>  TIFF* TIFF      rw+   Tagged Image File Format (LIBTIFF, Version 4.0.3)
> TIFF64* TIFF      rw-   Tagged Image File Format (64-bit) (LIBTIFF, Version 4.0.3)
>  TILE* TILE      r--   Tile image with a texture
>   TIM* TIM       r--   PSX TIM
>   TTC* TTF       r--   TrueType font collection (Freetype 2.5.2)
>   TTF* TTF       r--   TrueType font (Freetype 2.5.2)
>   TXT* TXT       rw+   Text
>  UBRL* BRAILLE   -w-   Unicode Text format
>   UIL* UIL       -w-   X-Motif UIL table
>  UYVY* UYVY      rw-   16bit/pixel interleaved YUV
>   VDA* TGA       rw-   Truevision Targa image
> VICAR* VICAR     rw-   VICAR rasterfile format
>   VID* VID       rw+   Visual Image Directory
>  VIFF* VIFF      rw+   Khoros Visualization image
>   VST* TGA       rw-   Truevision Targa image
>  WBMP* WBMP      rw-   Wireless Bitmap (level 0) image
>   WMF* WMF       r--   Windows Meta File
>   WMV  MPEG      rw+   Windows Media Video
>   WMZ* WMZ       r--   Compressed Windows Meta File
>   WPG* WPG       r--   Word Perfect Graphics
>     X* X         rw+   X Image
>   X3F  DNG       r--   Sigma Camera RAW Picture File
>   XBM* XBM       rw-   X Windows system bitmap (black and white)
>    XC* XC        r--   Constant image uniform color
>   XCF* XCF       r--   GIMP image
>   XPM* XPM       rw-   X Windows system pixmap (color)
>   XPS  XPS       r--   Microsoft XML Paper Specification
>    XV* VIFF      rw+   Khoros Visualization image
>   XWD* XWD       rw-   X Windows system window dump (color)
>     Y* RAW       rw+   Raw yellow samples
> YCbCr* YCbCr     rw+   Raw Y, Cb, and Cr samples
> YCbCrA* YCbCr     rw+   Raw Y, Cb, Cr, and alpha samples
>    YUV* YUV       rw-   CCIR 601 4:1:1 or 4:2:2
>
> * native blob support
> r read support
> w write support
> + support for multiple images
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much all free / open-source RAW converters, including all the other recommendations given so far (ImageMagick and Darktable), are based on the [dcraw](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dcraw) command-line tool by Dave Coffin.

Dcraw can do pretty much anything that commercial RAW decoders can, at least up to the limits of the developers' ability to reverse engineer the various proprietary RAW formats that camera vendors keep coming up with.
In fact, it's what ImageMagick (as [recommended](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/9944/1078) by Steve Barnes) [uses internally to decode RAW files.](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/formats/#crw)

If you're just looking to quickly batch-decode a bunch of NEF files, and have some familiarity with the Unix command line, you could just use the [dcraw command-line interface](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/dcraw.1.html) directly.
Alas, the one thing it *doesn't* do is write out JPEG files, but you can always pipe the PPM output from dcraw into [cjpeg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/saucy/man1/cjpeg.1.html) or ImageMagick to convert it to JPEG.

However, if you want to adjust things like exposure and white balance in your photos while decoding them, you'll most likely want to use a GUI front-end like [UFRaw](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UFRaw), [Darktable](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darktable) or [RawTherapee](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RawTherapee).  All of these are cross-platform tools, so they should run on both Windows and Linux.

Since you say you're mostly interested in batch converting multiple photos at a time, I'd also recommend the [Rawstudio](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rawstudio) front-end, which is designed primarily for this purpose.  However, it does not currently seem to have a Windows port, so it'd only be a solution on Linux.

Comment: At first I did find dcraw when I was doing my initial searching but I found it to be a little bit inconvenient to convert twice. Still great app though. I'll be editing all that stuff before hand (which is why its in RAW in the first place and not in JPEG from the camera) so mainly my main problem is converting. I'll probably be using the command line for simplicity, make a simple script to do it automatically. Very detailed answer! Thanks for that!

Comment: Note that there are some adjustments (such as, notably, exposure correction) that you really want to do *before* converting to JPEG, because JPEG only supports 8-bit color, and so loses much of the dynamic range of your RAW photos. (If you have an image editor that supports 16-bit TIFF or some HDR image format like EXR, you could convert the images to those without dynamic range loss; but at that point, it's probably easier to keep them in NEF format, or possibly in DNG if you don't like NEF for some reason.)

Comment: Yeah that's what I plan on doing. Literally the only reason I need to convert them is to print them off at my local photo lab.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at online NEF converter at [Raw.pics.io](https://raw.pics.io/convert-nef-to-jpeg). It is different from other online converters in a way that it performs everything on the client-side. It should work for you both on Linux and Windows.

Comment: Are you associated with that software? If so, you should disclose that in your answer.